# How to solve T(n)=4T(n/4)+n^2 by recursion tree and master theorem?

Tags: recurrence

> T(n) = 4T(n/4) + n^2 (if n=1, T(1)=c for some positive constant)

---

I asked [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2712660/539795) but no one answered.

What I want to ask is the answer to solving by master theorem and recursion tree about the same problem.

The conclusion is below sentences.

> 1. Master theorem = theta(n^2)
> 2. Recursion tree = theta(n^2 log_4 n)

---

How to solve and what is the answer?

Comment: Show how you got to these conclusions, especially the recursion tree one.

Comment: "Nobody answered" - you only waited three hours.  Be more patient.   Please [do not re-post your question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 0):

In the first level we have `O(n^2)` time-complexity. For the second level we have `4` times `O(n/4)`. For the next level `4*4` times `O(n/(4*4))` and so on.

So we have

[image]

**PS:**

The last part is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with `a=1` and `q = 1/4` summed upto `m` which `m` is equal to `log_4(n)`.

Depth of recursion tree can calculate from `n/4^i = c` formula. So `h = log_4(n)`.